# Manualy Creating TSQL server .BAK File from code

Tags: c#, t-sql, database-backups

I’m trying to write about 70 million data rows into an SQL server as fast as possible, the Bulk inserter is taking to long to write my chunks so I’m trying to manually create a .BAK file from my C# code to speed up the import to multiple other SQL servers.

Is there any Documentation about the structure of .BAK files? I've tried to find anything on google but all results jut show how to ex/import BAK Files using SQL.

Comment: No, the format of SQL Server's backup files is entirely proprietary and undocumented. There are third-party tools that know how to read/write them to some extent by having reverse engineered stuff, all of which are very expensive and prone to breaking with new versions. You are going to be *much* better off investigating *why* your "bulk inserter is taking too long". Using bulk insert most effectively is not necessarily obvious. Are you using `bcp`, `BULK INSERT` or `SqlBulkCopy`? The latter especially has some pitfalls that can easily tank your performance.

Comment: .BAK files do not work like other typical files such as .JPEG or .TXT. They are instead specific to the software that is creating them. There is no REAL obvious way to answer this question, because we don't know the actual format of that file.

Comment: The fastest way is to use one of the online SQL Command Line tools.  I use SQLCMD.EXE a lot and is built into the power script tools.  See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/command-prompt-utility-reference-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017.  You can create a bat file from c# and then run utility from a process if you need to automate.

Comment: I’m currently using `SqlBulkCopy` with data tables of 50.000 rows which are giving me the fastest write speeds in my benchmarks. it usually takes about 2 seconds for one batch to be processed which isn’t really bad but with the amount of data I need to write the time stacks up, so I’m further trying to sped up the writes.

Comment: A few pointers: 1) `DataTable` writes quickly but is very memory inefficient, which eats GC time; consider making your own `IDataReader` implementation (even a naive one that uses reflection tends to beat `DataTable`). 2) bulk insert in a heap or even a memory-optimized table, and leverage parallelism. TDS does not window packets and thus naturally bottlenecks on linear insert speed. 3) apropos packets: use `packet size=32767` in your connection string to maximize bandwidth. 4) consider using .NET Core 2.2 if you don't already -- it's faster than .NET Full.

Comment: I've written a bit about `SqlBulkCopy` and its problems [here](https://jeroen-mostert.github.io/sqlbulkcopy1/) and [here](https://jeroen-mostert.github.io/sqlbulkcopy2/). These will probably not help you directly in making things faster, but possibly worth reading nonetheless.